# Setting up Prettier on PhpStorm 2019.1.3

Tags: phpstorm, prettier

I have Prettier enabled in the plugins. The question is simply, where are these settings? Folder permissions or what?  The picture where they are showing is from the intellij-support website. The picture with the question mark is with the settings on my PhpStorm

[image]

Comment: Why? Because the screenshot from the help/support website is from newer IDE version. Your 2019.1.3 is soon to be 3 years old. Get the latest PhpStorm version (2021.3.3) and check there.

Comment: So, basically your answer is, that PhpStorm 2019.1.3 can't setup Prettier or what?

Comment: My answer means: newer version simply has MORE options / improvements compared to your 3 years old version. Prettier can be set up in your version, it will just work a bit differently (the way you invoke it). Just check the Prettier section in these blog posts: 1) 2020.1 -- https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2020/04/webstorm-2020-1/#prettier-on-save 2) 2020.2 -- https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2020/07/webstorm-2020-2/#using_prettier_as_the_default_formatter -- you can see the difference just between 2020.1 and 2020.2 versions (more options)

Comment: I know it can, can't figure out how, which is pretty ridicules. Even for a version 3 years old, its not 2009, but 2019 and that is something basic.

Comment: Here, official Help page for 2019.1 version: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.1/prettier.html . What exactly does not work for you? You do not know how to invoke Prettier, or something else?

Comment: well, when I make a selection and hit format with prettier nothing happens, not to mention, that it does not seem to have option on save etc.etc. Found this as well https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10456-prettier/reviews So basically the answer to this question is: "Use VS code". Cuz obviously on that version it's a broken/half feature. "Sorry I just read that it was available starting with 2018.1 Got it now." so, yeah, don't know what's wrong but I won't waste anymore time.

Answer (score 2):

A possibility to run Prettier on Save has been introduced in PhpStorm 2020.1; if upgrading the IDE is not an option for you, I can only suggest setting it up as a [file watcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.1/using-file-watchers.html?section=Windows%20or%20Linux) in  in **Preferences | Tools | File Watchers**  and make sure that **Auto-save edited files to trigger the watcher** (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.1/using-file-watchers.html?section=Windows%20or%20Linux#ws_filewatcher_advanced_options) is disabled

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, if you want to use Prettier with PhpStorm 2019.1.3 you need to install it with npm like this  [jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.1/prettier.html](https://%20jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.1/prettier.html) and setup the configuration of it in the **package.json** under "prettier" key. Then you have to right-click on the file and select **"Reformat with prettier"**. Maybe you can set hotkey for Prettier somewhere, the default ones do not work for me for some reason. If you want your code to be automatically formatted on save you need to install this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions/versions **"Save Actions"**. I installed 2.2.0 because it has support for 2018+.Then - because I couldn't find the place where you can change default formatting tool to **"Prettier"** you can setup the configuration under Settings->Editor->Code Style->choose the language you desire and then configure it. Could not find a way to setup prettier without json config or after setting it up to make it work on "Save" action. Answering this just because it might help somebody somewhere.